# IE8: How to set focus to a popup and back without blinking orange

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-8, shortcut

There are two windows: a parent window, and a child window. The parent can focus the child with a shortcut, and the child can give the focus back with a shortcut.

I have a test website [here](http://test.nedfox.net/FocusProblem/default.aspx). Just open the website in a new browser window, and try it in IE8.
This both works as expected:

1. Click on the parent window, and press `f`: the child gets focus
2. Click on the child window, and press `esc`: parent gets focus

But it does not work if you combine 1 and 2:

- Click on parent window and press f: child gets focus. Now press esc: the parent starts blinking but does not come to the front!

I tried a lot of different approaches, but I just can´t get it stable without blinking. It looks like if a window gets focus with a shortcut, then you can't return the focus without the blinking.

The problem only exists in IE8! It works great in IE9.

Does anyone know a workaround or any kind of solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried triggering a 'click' on the child/parent window after the focus event using jQuery?

Comment: Just tested your site in Firefox on Mac and the "Press esc" does not work.

Comment: What type of window is it? Is it a popup or a div overlay? Sorry, I am on an iPhone commuting atm

Comment: Confirmed, not working on Firefox here. Looks like its not possible at all to 'give the focus back' from the child to the parent there?

Comment: @AndrewWillis: It's a popup window (window.open)

Comment: if you can insert your code into new popup window like `JQuery UI`, make background and one window with table and div and send your data in that and not need to open new window or else it. Try it!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with IE 8 and Windows XP. Microsoft says they have fixed it, but so far they have released two "fixes" and the problem still exists.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979954

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973528

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried that ?

```
window.blur();
window.opener.focus();
```

Comment: Yes I did. It looks as if it is working, because the popup is going away, but still the parent does not get focus and starts blinking until you click it. It's also not working if you have more then 1 window open, then you see the window that is on top, not the one you give focus.